# Invalid boolean value using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests for posting data in dpd api. If I post the data:

```
{
"job_id": null,
"collectionOnDelivery": false,
"invoice": null,
"collectionDate": "2012-05-01T09:00:00",
"consolidate": null,
"consignment": []
}
```

using requests, I am getting the response 200, with error as

```
{"errorCode":"1008","errorType":"Validation","errorMessage":"Invalid boolean value","obj":"collectionOnDelivery"}
```

I modified the value of `collectionOnDelivery` as 0 and tried, but got the same error message. Can anyone help in this?

Comment: How're you posting it? Can you show exactly the code? If not, there's nothing I can do to help but make random (likely unhelpful) guesses.

Comment: `collectionOnDelivery` needs to be encoded as a Python boolean, `False`, rather than `false` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess "null" and "false" aren't a variable or a type you created. In python it is "None" instead of "null", also you need to capitalize first letter of "false" So try this:

```
{
"job_id": None,
"collectionOnDelivery": False,
"invoice": None,
"collectionDate": "2012-05-01T09:00:00",
"consolidate": None,
"consignment": []
}
```